# Quick CSS-Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

- - - EDIT - - -
      Active page state working now. How do I prevent the hover effect from still rolling over on the active page's menu button now? Like I want the audio button to stay blue on the audio.html page, rather than rolling over to grey hover state when mouse over.
- - - ORIGINAL POST - - -

I have a simple menu with CSS and a jquery function, menu sprite and all... Each section of the site has it's own html file to keep things simple... As of right now, the normal link state and hover function works, I'm having trouble getting the active page state to work and shift the sprite accordingly. Here is the code I'm working with at the moment.

[The HTML](http://www.deviousbeats.net/_fademenu_/index.html)

[The CSS](http://www.deviousbeats.net/_fademenu_/css/style.css)

The menu sprite is at /images/menusprite.png in relation to the index.html (it wont let me link it or post the image directly)

With the current structure I have setup, the menu buttons rollover to the 2nd grey state in the sprite, I would like to set the active page's corresponding menu button to shift to the blue state to indicate that's the current page being viewed. I have attempted to specify a class for such a function a few ways, but I don't know jquery at all and either way I setup the CSS, it fades the button completely out to an opacity of 0 instead of the active page's button being in the blue state. So what's the proper way, given this particular structuring, to specify the active class in the CSS & the page's corresponding li element?

Comment: try adding dynamic class (using jquery) to `<li>` tag.

Comment: Ok, update. I got the active state working for the proper li element for each page. How do i prevent it from rolling over to the hover state for the active page now? In other words, if I'm on the audio page, I want the audio button to remain blue, not rollover to the grey hover state when the mouse moves over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the hover function by checking your `active` class on your link:

```
$("ul#nav li a").css({"opacity" : 0}).hover(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) { return; }
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 1}, 400); //Change fade-in speed

    }, function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) { return; }
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : 0}, 200);//Change fade-out speed
});
```

**Note:**
This works if the active class is on your `a` tag. When it's on your `li`-element, you have to look for it using this line:

```
if($(this).parents('li').hasClass('active')) { return; }
```

Here's an example:

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHcFb/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ugh... finally. Thank you so very very very much Nirazul. It works the way I need it to now. Hopefully this migraine headache will start to fade away now   :P